# Example of a set based on random variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory, random-variables, normal-distribution, stochastic-analysis

I have $S_N = \Sigma^N_{n=1} X_n$, where $X_n$ is a random variable that takes either 1, -1, 0, each with probability 1/3. I know that $\frac{S_N}{\sqrt N}$ converges in distribution to a mean-zero normally distributed random variables, say $Y$.

However I am trying to come up with a set $A$, for which $\Bbb P(Y \in A)=0$, but for which $\Bbb P(\frac{S_N}{\sqrt N} \in A)= \frac{1}{2}$ for positive odd integers N, but am struggling to do so.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: if $X_n$'s are independent $S_N /N$ converges to $0$, if you want normal distribution you will need $S_N / \sqrt{N}$.

Comment: @BoraDoğan Apologies, that was a typo. I have corrected that now. Thank you for noticing!

Comment: @BoraDoğan: shouldn't $\mu=0, \sigma=1$ to get $\frac{\sum_k X_k}{\sqrt{n}} \to_n Z(0,1)$

Comment: Yes, normal distribution is used for Gaussian. If it is unit variance, zero mean it is standard normal distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note Bora Dogan's comment - we are interested in $S_N / \sqrt{N}$, since $S_N / N$ converges in distribution to the expectation by the law of large numbers.

Consider trying $A = \left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}, \frac{3}{\sqrt{N}}, \cdots, \frac{N - 2}{\sqrt{N}}, \sqrt{N}\right\}$. The reason $\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{S_N}{\sqrt{N}} \in A\right) = 1/2$ is because for odd integers $N$, the summation is symmetric about zero. It never takes on the value zero, and for every $x > 0$, the probabilities of $S_N = x$ and $S_N = -x$ are equivalent. Note further that $\mathbb{P}(S_N > N) = 0$, so the elements of set $A$ are the only positive values that $S_N / \sqrt{N}$ may take.

But as $Y$ is normally distributed and continuous, $\mathbb{P}\left(Y \in A\right) = 0$ because $A$ is measure zero (it is countable).

Comment: Makes total sense now, thank you! PS, i edited the typo in my original question